# Typescript Duplicate identifier 'Node'

Tags: typescript

When compiling the following typescript:

```
class Node {
}
```

It works in the playground but not using VS2013 or grunt-typescript which generates the error

```
TS2000: Duplicate identifier 'Node'
```

I guess it can only be because its a reserved word but I have searched the typescript spec for reserved words and can't find any. Is there a list available and why is such a common class name reserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Node` is already an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) in JavaScript. It's not a reserved word, but it is a built-in thing that you don't want to accidently overwrite at runtime (you would break other libraries).

```
> Node.prototype
    Node {insertBefore: function, replaceChild: function, removeChild: function, appendChild: function, hasChildNodes: function…}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like there is a library file:

[lib.d.ts](https://github.com/c9/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts)

That contains 8 KLOC of typescript without any form of module or namespace that is causing me all sorts of name clashes. Frustrating given the compiler doesn't give any locations and I spend hours tearing apart my build system looking for some sort of fault.

Comment: The lib.d.ts gives the typescript compiler information about standard javascript methods (methodname, typed parameters and typed returnvalue). This is exactly why you want to use typescript...